# What does login item "System Events" do?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, login-items

I have an item "System Events" under "Login Items" for the admin account on a MacBook that is running macOS High Sierra (upgraded from Sierra). Is this login item part of macOS and what does it do?

Comment: This is what you are looking for: https://macosx.com/threads/system-events-what-is-it.285312/ I have comfortably removed it from my startup items without any issues arising whatsoever.

Comment: @ProGrammer Thx, if you want to turn your comment into an answer I shall accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are looking for: [Explanation](https://macosx.com/threads/system-events-what-is-it.285312/).
I have comfortably removed it from my startup items without any issues arising whatsoever.