# What is "System Events"?

Tags: applescript, big-sur

I mostly see AppleScript scripts that say something should be called in "System Events". What exactly is System Events now?

What I definitely know is that there is it an app and that is `/System/Library/ CoreServices/System\ Events.app`.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308208/what-does-login-item-system-events-do.

Comment: IMO... More important then what it is, look at the **System Events** _dictionary_ in the **Library** (**⇧⌘L**) in **Script Editor** and see what it can do, as that really is more important in regards to **AppleScript**.

Comment: Also, Google [what is system events in macos](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+system+events+in+macos&client=safari&rls=en&ei=FdVUYMvoBZG35gK7gL7oAg&oq=what+is+system+events+in+macos&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EANQAFgAYPe7BGgAcAJ4AIABY4gBY5IBATGYAQCqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiLx4SD57zvAhWRm1kKHTuADy0Q4dUDCAw&uact=5)

Answer (score 9):

System Events is a faceless background app provided by Apple that gives AppleScript access to certain system functions and attributes. For example, we can use the app to change the desktop picture, control the user interface of other applications, change the screen saver, navigate the file system hierarchy, and more. Open Script Editor, choose *File➔Open Dictionary...*, and choose System Events from the list of apps. This will show you the AppleScript commands you can invoke.

Comment: **System Events** by default is already in the **Library** in **Script Editor**, just **⇧⌘L** instead.